# How to pass string to content of meta tag for template?

Tags: django, django-templates

```
    {% if is_inner_page %}
      <meta name="description" content={{ description }}>
  {% else %}
      <meta name="description" content="Text sample"/>
  {% endif %}
```

When i passed string to template with render in view, I get only first word of string in content, so how to pass full string of description to template? If i pass not in content, then all is ok, please help me :(

Comment: Try  `<meta name="description" content="{{ description }}">`

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the content between quotes, so `content="…"`:

```
 <meta name="description" content="{{ description }}">
```